App that outputs diagrams that display some of the story or play structure of the input story or play
I wonder whether there exists any software that takes a novel or story book for children, and, outputs, some of the patterns into which the novel or story can be broken down into, from a mathematical perspective (outputting diagrams and schemes, also patterns).
Thanks.
